# How to retrieve the amazon api product price only for amazon merchantID

Tags: php, amazon-product-api

Here is my code, but it returns the lowest price from third party seller, what I'm doing wrong ? I'm using response group Offers as it seems it's the way to get results according to documentation.

```
function getAmazonPrice($region, $asin) {

    $xml = aws_signed_request($region, array(
        "Operation" => "ItemLookup",
        "ItemId" => $asin,
        "IncludeReviewsSummary" => False,
        "ResponseGroup" => "Medium, Offers",
        "MerchantId" => "Amazon",
    ));

    $item = $xml->Items->Item;
    $title = htmlentities((string) $item->ItemAttributes->Title);
    $url = htmlentities((string) $item->DetailPageURL);
    $image = htmlentities((string) $item->MediumImage->URL);
    $price = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->Amount);
    $code = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->CurrencyCode);
    $qty = htmlentities((string) $item->OfferSummary->TotalNew);

    if ($qty !== "0") {
        $response = array(
            "code" => $code,
            "price" => number_format((float) ($price / 100), 2, '.', ''),
            "image" => $image,
            "url" => $url,
            "title" => $title
        );
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue.

What I did is assuming when AMAZON offers a discount, it is in SalePrice:

$SalePrice=$xmlProduct->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->SalePrice->Amount;

if that node doesnt exist, then there is no discount, just use the Listing Price:
$xmlProduct->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Price->Amount